# How to get all possible solutions for a given equation, with only the result known

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to write an algorithm in C++ that can get all possible valid solutions for an equation such as x + y * z - c % d / e = 33, where the operators are random and include +, -, /, *, %, &, | and ^ (last 3 being bitwise operators) and the numbers that can be used come from a fixed range such as (1,2,3,4,5).

My current implementation generates all permutations with repetition (using the below code)

```
vector<vector<int>> generate_permutations(int start, int end, int length) {
    vector<vector<int>> result;
    if (length == 0) {
        // Base case: return empty list
        result.push_back({});
        return result;
    }
    // Recursive case: generate permutations of length-1 and add all possible values to the end
    vector<vector<int>> sub_permutations = generate_permutations(start, end, length - 1);
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
        for (vector<int>& sub_permutation : sub_permutations) {
            sub_permutation.push_back(i);
            result.push_back(sub_permutation);
            sub_permutation.pop_back();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

and then evaluates the equation with each permutation to see if it is valid or not, before adding that to a set of valid solutions.

But this is very slow for even modestly sized ranges, and I was wondering if there was a faster algorithm (either a faster algorithm to generate permutations with repetition or a mathematical way of obtaining all solutions) or a better approach.

Comment: You don't need to recompute `y * z` if a permutation doesn't affect these values, etc.

Comment: [std::next_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) might be useful.

Comment: Use an SMT solver. https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/wiki#background Is a good place to start.

Comment: Do you really need it for all possible equations? That will definitely be slow for larger equations. Maybe you can somehow restrict the class of equations you are interested in.